# Getting a resultCode from a PendingIntent that starts an Activity?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Is there any possible way to get the resultCode from an activity that's launched from a pendingIntent? The onFinished listener for PendingIntent.send() is only called immediately with a resultCode of RESULT_CANCELED, which doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The nature of the PendingIntent is such that you can never tell WHEN it will be invoked: the calling Ativity may be completely shutdown or possibly even uninstalled by the time it is started. Therefore there can be no reliable way to receive the response with `startActivityForResult`.